# SharePoint: How to turn off auto increment for field ID in List?

Tags: sharepoint, listitem

I need to synchronize data from mysql into listitem in sharepoint, and keep values of ID when synchronized to ListItem, but I can not insert ID value.

Comment: [Click here](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/) This would be a better platform to ask this question.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior of SharePoint's ID field cannot be modified.

The solution is to use a different field, such as a new Number field, to store the ID value from your MySql data.